# Proper way to upgrade from llvm-g++-4.2 to g++-4.7 on Mac

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew

I have Lion 10.7.3 with the Command-line tool installed. I wanted to experiment with C++11, so I used homebrew to install GCC 4.7 as documented [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/issues/20).

How can I now upgrade the /usr/bin/g++ to be the one installed by Homebrew? Is it as simple as symlinking it? I just want to double check and make sure. Thanks!

Comment: Note that clang has C++11 features http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Comment: This is probably a very bad idea. Why not leave /usr/bin/g++ alone, and specify your g++ in the relevant way, e.g., by passing "CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++" to ./configure or make, or putting /usr/local/bin above /usr/bin on the path, or explicitly using g++-4.7 instead of g++?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that gcc-4.7 doesn't have many features that are available in apple-gcc-4.0, apple-gcc-4.2, and llvm-gcc-4.2, which means -arch flags, newer ObjC features, etc. won't work.

Comment: @abarnert, thanks a lot for your suggestion. I was just trying to setup CodeRunner http://krillapps.com/coderunner with a C++11 compiler. I ended up just installing gcc 4.7 via Homebrew and then configured just the CodeRunner to point to gcc 4.7 and left everything else untouched. Thanks so much for your wisdom. =)

Comment: @abarnert: That's the way to do it. You should turn your comment in to an answer so this can get accepted and closed out.

Answer (score 3):

First, are you sure you need g++ 4.7? As you can see from the [C++11 implementation status](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) page, recent versions of clang support most of C++11 too. Of course there are still things that g++ handles and clang doesn't, but there are also still things that clang supports and g++ doesn't. And, more importantly, you already *have* a recent version of clang, from Apple, configured and ready to go, as your default compiler. Plus, g++ after 4.2 doesn't support Mac extensions like, say, `-arch`, which means you can't use it to build a whole lot of third-party software (because most configure scripts assume that if you're on a Mac, your compiler supports Mac extensions).

---

But if you want g++ 4.7, you can do it. Just not by trying to replace `/usr/bin/g++` with a different version. Never replace anything in `/usr/bin` (or `/System`) with non-Apple stuff except in a few very rare cases (when you have a strong reassurance from someone who knows what they're talking about).

A better thing to do is to just install another compiler in parallel. Just let Homebrew install its favorite way (so it installs into some prefix like /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/4.7, then symlinks all the appropriate stuff into /usr/local/bin, etc.), and use it that way.

When compiling your code, instead of writing `g++`, write `/usr/local/bin/g++`, or `g++-4.7`.

If you get tired of doing that, put `/usr/local/bin` higher on your PATH that `/usr/bin`, or create a shell alias, or stick it in the environment variable CXX and write `$CXX` instead of `g++`.

If you're using a GUI IDE, you should be able to configure it to use your compiler by setting the path to it somewhere. (Unless you're using Xcode, which you can only configure to work with Apple-tested compilers.)

---

This is all you need for experimenting with your own code. If you want to compile third-party applications with this compiler, that may be a bit more complicated. You don't often actually compile each source file and link the result together; you just do `configure && make` and let them do the heavy lifting for you.

Fortunately, most packages will respect the standard environment variables, especially `CXX` for specifying a default C++ compiler and `CC` for a default C compiler. (That's why I suggested the name `CXX` above.)

Just remember that, again, g++ 4.7 doesn't support Mac extensions, so if you're not prepared to debug a bunch of autoconf-based configure scripts complaining that your compiler can't generate code because it assumed it could throw `-arch x86_64` at any compiler on a Mac, etc., don't do this.